# heroku login issue on windows powershell

Tags: authentication, heroku

When I login Heroku in windows powershell，I am getting the following error:

```sh
C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:29
        throw err;
        ^t

CLIError: timed out
    at Object.error (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\@oclif\errors\lib\index.js:22:17)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Program Files\heroku\client\node_modules\@heroku-cli\command\lib\login.js:27:38)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  oclif: { exit: 2 },
  code: undefined
}
```

What does it mean and how can I get rid of it?